# How to search on phrases in Spring Data Solr 1.0

Tags: java, spring, solr, spring-data, spring-data-solr

I have a search query that contains quoted phrases and other words and would like to use spring-data-solr 1.0.

Here is an example query: `dog "siamese cat" penguin`

I've been trying something like,

```
new Criteria("myfield").contains("dog")
        .and(new Criteria("myfield").contains("siamese cat"))
        .and(new Criteria("myfield").contains("penguin"));
```

That was what I was trying until I saw that `contains()` throws an exception when it contains spaces.

Lately I'm trying `.expression()` but not sure how it works or if that's even a viable solution.

Any ideas? Thanks /w

Comment: `.is()` appears to be working, but not sure if that's matching `*siamese cat*`.

Comment: Yes. is will do a phrase in case of whitespace in between. But * will be escaped. Expression will take given string and do no further processing.

Answer (score 3):

i solve it with expression:

```
new Criteria("myfield").expression("\"siamese cat\"")
```

Comment: Try this .expression("(siamese AND cat)")

Answer (score 1):

This works for me... since space is a special char just escape it:

```
new Criteria("myfield").expression("siamese\ cat")
```

Comment: ClientUtils.escapeQueryChars(value)